# Deprecate only a default protocol implementation in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, attributes, protocols

Consider I have a protocol `Test`. I want to provide a default implementation for a newly added property called `newProperty` so that 10 other projects don't have to add it in their mocks implementing `Test` protocol for unit test. But for any real use case, I want people **NOT** to rely on this default implementation and add their own implementation or use a class that correctly implements this protocol.

So if I were to add a `@available(*, deprecated, message)` before the default implementation would Xcode warn users who use the default implementation only. Or will it warn even if a `Implementor` class instance was used to access `newProperty`?

```
protocol Test {

    var newProperty: CGFloat { get }

    ...
}

extension Test {
    
    @available(*, deprecated, message: "Please ignore default implementation")
    var newProperty: CGFloat {
        get {
            return -1.0
        }
    }
}

class Implementor: Test {
    
    var newProperty: CGFloat 

    init() {
         newProperty = 100
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Is this a reusable component? Or do you have access to all your projects that uses this Test protocol?

Comment: It's a reusable component, and I don't have access to every project.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve it by differentiating your test target and making the extension code available to your test target only.

To differentiate different test target in code you can add `preprocessor macros` and `custom swift flags` to your test target's build setting.

Select your test target and search **preprocessor macros** in build setting and add `TESTING=1` to all the build configurations available

[image]

Being in same target add a custom flag by searching other swift flags and add `-DTESTING` to all the configurations available

[image]

Finally in your code, wrap extension default implementation as

```
#if TESTING
extension Test {
    var newProperty: CGFloat {
        get {
            return -1.0
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

Now if you try to confirm to `Test` protocol in your main project target

```
class MyOwnView: UIView, Test {
    
}
```

You will get error: [image]

If you open test target and confirm the protocol

```
    class SomeView: UIView, Test {

        
    }
```

It wont show any errors.

Though you dont have access to all the 10 projects, all you have to ask them to do is to add this macro and custom flag to their test target and thats pretty much doable I guess

Comment: But they simple `@available` won't achieve the same thing? Is there anything simple I can change. I was also looking at `#warning()`